# Photoshop slices not working properly (only see one when exporting)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I think this screenshot is self-explanatory.

Shouldn't I see all of the created slices when I export for the web? Instead, I just see one! Could it be that the file have a very high resolution (4k x 3k)?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I tried to save anyway and it works! It gives me all my slices in separate files. Why then I see only one in the export window? Not so much of an issue now, btw...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your zoom at 100% (when you are working with your image at 33%, as you can see in the top bar). What you are seeing is the top left corner of the first slice.

Reduce the zoom and you will see all of them :)

Comment: Watching all of the slices while zooming out, I was feeling a little bit of an idiot :)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't worry, the placing of the zoom is not exactly the most intuitive thing.